# Decrypting files without running Python code

Tags: python, encryption

I am able to encrypt an excel file with AES using PyCrypto and decrypt it as well using my python code. My goal is to encrypt an excel file and email it to someone else. The problem is that the other person will also need to install the Python decryption software, run the code, type in the password, which would finally decrypt the file. I would prefer a way for them to simply click on the encrypted file, which should open up a text box where they can type the password and the file is decrypted without having to install my python code.

I have been searching for something that could do this, but I was not able to find someone who has done something like I am trying to do.

Comment: This would require either a piece of software on their computer that knows how to do the decryption and which file types to handle (which you specify you don't want them to have to install code), or for the decryption and interface code to be part of your file that first runs the code, and if the password is received, then shows the embedded file (like a self-extracting password protected archive).

Comment: These "self-decrypting archives" are a bad idea. They are difficult to maintain, platform-specific, and they train users to run executables they know nothing about. I'll admit that gpg is insanely painful and complicated to use, but that's what it sounds like you should be using. However, if you must do it your way you might look into https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/ or similar.